# How to show short description via invoice admin panel

Tags: orders, invoice

I want show short description via admin admin like this image. 
[image: How to show short description in red border]
Please tell me how to show it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include the short description in invoice,edit the file in

> app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\items\column\name.phtml

Find the line,

```
<h5 class="title"><span id="order_item_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>_title"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></span></h5>
```

Add the code after that line,

```
<?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());?>
<div><strong><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Short Description') ?>:</strong><?php echo $product->getShortDescription();?></div>
```

I have just included the short description, change as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Add custom code in file `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\items\column\name.phtml`

```
<?php if($_item->getProduct()->getShortDescription()):?>
         <div><strong><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Short Description') ?>:</strong> <?php echo $_item->getProduct()->getShortDescription();?></div>

<?php endif;?>
```

Add above code after bellow code

```
<h5 class="title"><span id="order_item_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>_title"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></span></h5>
```